# Missing "sessionid" cookie using SessionAuthentication

Tags: python, django, authentication

I got the issue that the sessionid cookie seems not to be saved after deploying on the Amazon EC2.

In the setting.py I wrote

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

I login via a rest call that is defined such as

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework import status, views
from rest_framework.response import Response


class LoginView(views.APIView):

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self, request):
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get("username"),
            password=request.data.get("password"))

        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': 'Username or password incorrect'
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        return Response({"username": request.data.get("username")})


class LogoutView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

On the local windows machine that works well and the sessionid cookie is available and used for all rest-calls. However, using the Amazon EC2, that cookie is not created.

Can someone help?

THX Lazloo

Comment: Does this answer looks suitable for your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51809164/4996863

Comment: Unfortunately not. I already have created an admin user and clearing the cookies does not lead to the reproduction of this error on the local machine.